# Split a data by length, nearest delimiter and use constant value for next line

Tags: sql, regex, oracle, oracle11g

I need to split the string based using oracle sql on the below Rules

**Rule 1:** Split string of length 10 char.
**Rule 2:** If length of the splitted string is greater than 10, then split that string by last delimiter (,) if the value fall greater than length of 10 characters
**Rule 3:** If it is greater than 10 characters, then line should end up with ‘-‘ and the new line should start by ‘99’ 
**Rule 4:** The line with ‘11’ should also be 10 characters along the ‘11’.

**Input**

```
Row1 - 01,234,45689,012,3456,7890123,12
```

**Output**

```
01,234,-
11,45689,-
11,12,345,-
11,789012,-
11,312
```

As suggested, I used the non-assertion in oracle

```
.{1,10}$|.{0,9},|.{1,10}
```

This gives the 10 characters but I need to add the constant at end and starting of new line.

Comment: If you still need the output total to be 10 chars plus the `-`, the best you can do is adjust the upper bounds `{,10}` to match the addition of `11,` by reducing it by 3 chars `(.{1,7}$|.{0,6},|.{1,7})`. Then replace with `11,\1-` But the _last_ replace will then have the `-` at the end as well. In general, its in the scope now where it needs logic `if/then/else`. And, I don't see how you've obtained the last output (11,312 drop a comma there?) and/or what `99` has to do with it.

Comment: Sorry my mistake, the input last value should be ,312 and the 99 is 11.   SELECT DISTINCT regexp_replace('01,234,45689,12,12,3456,789012,312','(.{1,7}$|.{0,6},|.{1,7})', '11,\1-' || CHR(13) || CHR(10) ) txt
FROM dual
CONNECT BY regexp_substr('01,234,45689,12,12,3456,789012,312', '(.{1,7}$|.{0,6},|.{1,7})', 1, LEVEL) IS NOT NULL  The Output is  11,01,234,-
11,45689,-
11,12,12,-
11,3456,-
11,789012,-
11,312-   You want to use if/then/else to remove '11' from first line and '-' from last line. Can you confirm whether the query is correct because without distinct it gives it returns duplicate.

Comment: It's been a while since I've done sql, but I guess the querry is correct. The regex looks correct, so does the output. You just have to trim off the first `11` and the last `-`.

Comment: Thanks. After long time they is same change in the requirement. The comma have to move to the next newline as 01,234-
11,45689-
11,12,345-
11,789012-
11,312